Can an application detect network requests from outside its application without rooting?
context: im building an appblocker application, and i have a foreground service. I would like to detect when the user opens a youtube short, and just redirect user home with a simple redirect_home intent.
through adb ive noted that yt makes a network request when you open yt shorts
https://s.youtube.com/api/stats/qoe?el=shortspage....
listening to logs outside of the application requires the user to root their phone. is there any way that doesnt require rooting? thank you!
Tried: getting adb logs with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");  but i can only get logs within the application. getting all logs requires user to root their phone.

No.  It would be a massive privacy and malware vector if an app could detect what network requests other apps make.  Generally if you want to block network requests, you write a VPN app.  That would require the apps to go through your VPN, but requires additional permissions and the user to set your app as the device's VPN.  See https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/vpn

cool, will look into it. thanks!

Depending on the app on network level you will may see an IP address if the app uses TLS 1.3 with encrypted headers. And reverse lookup will not tell you that the IP belongs to youtube. Note that Android 15 may already include an app blocking system if the featur available in the betas will make it into the final version.
